# Semi Unique Website Background concept. Video as Background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've seen this done, but up til now wasn't interested in doing it. Now I'm sitting here slightly bored wanting to play with a new idea I have which involves the idea of putting a video as the background on a page. Full width and height of the viewing pane (preferably resizes with the window if the window should resize). I'm just not really sure how to tackle this. I know its going to require me layering divs over divs with z-index as Im guessing the actual background property of any given browser doesn't directly support this. I guess my question is ultimately is how to handle the video? I need some means of playing it on a loop, thats not a player like flow player or whatever.

Comment: There would be little bandwidth left for your site.
Elements on the site could be extremely hard to see.

How about a large animated gif.
Or slowly change background images...5 second fade in/out?

Comment: You could also add sparkles that trail your cursor as you move it around!

Comment: Bandwidth I am not super concerned about. Its a small personal site of mine that really doesn't get all to much traffic this is more in the name of having a little fun. and LOL @Inerdia 10 years ago I may have taken that idea and ran with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jQuery plugin. I haven't tested it but it lets you set a youtube video as the site's background. (and from the example code, maybe also any element on the page).

[Tubular jQuery Plugin](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/)